# How to pull URL from open web browser in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, google-chrome

Need to pull URL from current web browser using Matlab. URL is a google maps URL that is constantly changing as the user moves around. Matlab code needs to be able to work in conjunction with the open google Chrome tab and pull the changing URL when the user specifies.

Not sure how to attack this - have tried using the web function but the google maps is running in Chrome, not the default matlab browser.

I’m trying to get away from my current method, which is copying and pasting the url from chrome into matlab every time there is a change.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it an alternative to use MATLAB's in-built (with the relevant toolbox) mapping tools? You'd likely spend less time debugging the interface you're considering and more time on everything else

Comment: If supported by chrome, a starting point could be to create a com server https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/actxserver.html.